# How to avoid loop at redirect_to :back?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using this helper at before filter

```
def has_current_firm
 if current_firm.nil?
   flash[:warning] = t :error_msg
   redirect_to :back
 end
end
```

but, sometimes it's dives to infinite loop
what the simplest way to make sure that referered controller is not equal to current?

Comment: Beware of :back, some browsers don't send the referer information

Comment: yap, the secod condition, when it must be redirected to root_url

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but just a note.

Rails 5 has [redirect_back](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_back):

```
redirect_back fallback_location: { action: "show", id: 5 }
redirect_back fallback_location: post
redirect_back fallback_location: "http://www.rubyonrails.org"
redirect_back fallback_location:  "/images/screenshot.jpg"
redirect_back fallback_location:  articles_url
redirect_back fallback_location:  proc { edit_post_url(@post) }
```

Its source:

```
def redirect_back(fallback_location,, **args)
  if referer = request.headers["Referer"]
    redirect_to referer, **args
  else
    redirect_to fallback_location, **args
  end
end
```